# How do I remove the tabs from the edit field collection form in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming

When editing a field collection on a node there are two tabs typically, view and edit. I wanted to remove them. Obviously I can hide them with CSS, but this feels like the wrong way to do it. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can do that from your themes page template file. They are printed as tabs variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this with code, you can use [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). Set the "type" to MENU_CALLBACK. This will still keep the path registered, but it will not show a tab. [More inforamtion](http://drupal.org/node/483324)

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to intercept these entries via hook_menu_alter, but what can I change to make them not appear? I still want the page to appear, just the tabs to not be visible.

Comment: Google fail! I figured this out: http://drupal.org/node/483324

Answer (score 4):

[tab tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) has just been ported to D7 a week ago and might be able to remove those tabs as well.

Comment: Nice! I will look.